# Erlang - Mnesia sync disc_copy with ram data

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I am observing a strange phenomenon. I have iterated over all my records in a table, and emptied a field. This has been completed successfully, as I get the record with the empty field.

However, my DCD and DCL files of the table are still huge(100mb+) and have kept the field value. Inside Erlang, I get all records correctly without the field value as expected - even after reboot.

I managed to remove the DCD and DCL files on my local machine and did something that re-created them from ram but I do not remember what, and so I cannot conceive the same result again.

Do we have procedures for this kind of situation, where the disc_copy is to be re-created from the data in ram?

Cheers!